# Windows Phone 8 isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to physically copy files to Isolated Storage using the `ISETool`? I'm trying to add a text file into Isolated Storage and then, through code, check if that file exists. When I do this, I get a "File does not exist" error.

If I add a file to Isolated Storage in code, it works successfully and I can access it in Isolated Storage via the `ISETool` to copy it to my PC.

Consider scenario 2:

I add a file into Isolated Storage in code, and then using the  `ISETool` get it back to my PC. Without modifying the file, I place the SAME FILE back to Isolated Storage and try to open it through code, I see the same "File does not Exist" error.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said how you're writing files to Isolated Storage.

Instead, consider using something like [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) for this as it makes it much easier to work with files in Isolated Storage.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ReplacingFilesinIsolatedStorage), you are able:

> ...to replace the files and directories in an app’s local folder on an
>   emulator or a device with files and directories from your computer....

Steps:

1. Deploy the app that you want to test to the emulator or a device.
2. Get the Product GUID for the app specified in the ProductID attribute of the App element of the WMAppManifest.xml file.
3. Open a Command prompt window and navigate to the location of ISETool.exe.
4. To replace all the files in the app’s local folder with files from your computer, type the following command using the Product GUID obtained in the previous steps and specify the source directory on your computer.

`ISETool.exe rs <xd|de> <product-id> <desktop-path>`

The following example shows a command that replaces the files and directories in an app’s local folder with the files from the directory "C:\Data\My Files" on your computer.

`ISETool.exe rs xd 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 "C:\Data\My Files"`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to copy to and from isostorage of phone or emulator 
try this to upload or download files into iso storage
for wp8.1 only 
[https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/](http://wptools.codeplex.com/)
for wp7
[Windows Phone 7 Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/releases)
for wp8
[Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/)

Comment: maine downvote nehi kiya tha. Jab kisi question ka answer dena thora describe kar dena kyun tumhara answer appropriate hai.